# Dependency between IEEE 802 and OSI model

Tags: ieee-802.11, osi

**My question is focussed on IEEE 802.11x for (WLAN) and 802.15.1 (Bluetooth)**

Wikipedia and other sources underline, that the mentioned IEEE standards just define the PHY and MAC layer from the OSI model.

[IEEE 802.11 is a set of media access control (MAC) and physical layer (PHY) specifications for implementing...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11)

[IEEE 802.15.1 defines physical layer (PHY) and Media Access Control (MAC) specification for wireless...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15)

But what is about the other layers? Where are they defined and whats their name?

In my opinion the IEEE standard and the protocol name WLAN and Bluetooth are very often mixed up.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
My question is not a duplicate of this [question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/osi-model-and-networking-protocols-relationship).

> How should a student (or professional for that matter) understand the
>   relationship between the OSI model and protocols he/she works with?

My question is about the mentioned IEEE standards (not the protocols) and the dependency to the OSI model.

Comment: Please note, the IEEE standard is NOT the protocol as in your question!

Comment: There is no relationship between ISO and IEEE, so there are no IEEE standards for the OSI model layers.  Two different organizations ,defining two different things for two different purposes.

Comment: The OSI model is just a model, and nothing in the real world adheres to the model, so nothing depends on the OSI model. Standards and protocols are written to serve a purpose and fill a need without regard to any theoretical model that was created to explain an ideal situation.The real world is more closely aligned with the IP model, although it, too, is just a model.

Answer (score 0):

IEEE 802 defines many standards covering the physical and the data link layer, most prominently Ethernet (802.3) and Wi-Fi (802.11).

For the network layer, the predominant standards IPv4 and IPv6 are defined by the IETF.

The IETF also defines the most common transport layer protocols used with IP (such as TCP and UDP) and many application layer protocols (SMTP, HTTP, IMAP, FTP, Telnet, SSH, ...).