# Session, presentation and application layer

Tags: cisco, security

I almost finished the ccna, in the meantime I'm following Pentesting courses, I noticed enough interesting protocols at the session level.  I wish I could understand them as I did with cisco, but I found only generic materials.  I wish I had something deeper, which could also include levels 6 and 7.  Where can I find what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OSI model is a theoretical model, and there aren't any protocols in use today that follow it.  So layers 5-7 are just "concepts."  In the TCP/IP model (closer to what is actually in use today), there are no session and presentation layers.  Everything is simply "application."    This [question and answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/osi-model-and-networking-protocols-relationship) may help you.